# Cocos2d menu is eating touches only on a portion of the screen

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene with 2 layers. The main layer and a hud layer above it. The hud just has a menu with its buttons and the timer label. I am using [CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers) so I can attach standard `UIGestureRecognizers` for each of the `CCSprites` in the middle of the screen on the main layer. The strange thing is that the menu seems to be eating all touch events for the area right of the red line. Not just at the bottom around the menu but all the way to to the top of the screen. If I don't add the menu to the layer or if I place that layer behind the main layer everything works ok, but that doesn't work visually for me. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
//The hud layer setup
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithArray:@[_recordButton, resetButton, debugButton, _playButton]];
[menu setPosition:ccp(windowSize.width - 225, 50)];
[menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:50];
[self addChild:menu];

//The scene setup in another class
self.mainLayer = [MainLayer node];
[self addChild:_mainLayer z:0];
self.hudLayer = [HudLayer node];
[self addChild:_hudLayer z:1];
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Edit:
I have tried setting the menu's priority `[menu setHandlerPriority:128];` and when that didn't work I subclassed `CCMenu` and overrode:

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:200 swallowsTouches:NO];
}
```

I've tried it with `swallowsTouches:` set to `NO` and `YES` with no difference.

Comment: Are you registering the HUD layer with the TouchDispatcher as well?

Comment: I just tried adding the `-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher` implementation above to the HUD layer and it appears it is never called.

Comment: You don't have to, I was just curious. But you would also have to register it yourself by calling `[HudLayer setTouchEnabled:YES]`. You can modify the priority of a particular `CCMenu` by calling `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] setPriority:1 forDelegate:myCCMenu];` Just keep in mind that touch priority is low-to-high, so lower numbers get higher priority.

Comment: Anyway, if you change the menu position, does the touch are get impacted? If you instead place it midscreen (windowSize.width/2,50), is half the screen "untouchable"?

Comment: Yes if I center it the right 1/2 of screen becomes untouchable.

Comment: I suspect the touch logic in either your mainlayer or its parent (parent to mainlayer and hud layer) is discarding the touches.

Comment: One would think but I don't have any standard touch logic. Only the `UIGestureRecognizers` on each individual `CCSprite` character and I've confirmed that none of those are firing.

Comment: Then probably an issue with how CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers handles touches. Just looking at the code quickly, I notice `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` loops through the node's parent to see if a valid touch was made. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that particular category, but I would start debugging there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `CCMenu` is defaulting to a `contentSize` that is equal to the device's screen size. This was making it effectively cover 1/2 the scene with the position I was using. So I just had to set the content size to something close to the actual menu item's overall size: `[menu setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 50)];`

Comment: You can also check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962072/cocos2dmenu-click-detection-is-a-bit-off-to-bottom-left-whenever-using-a-custo/30963564#30963564

This is very frustrating. Just added in comment for reference.